# Display/log tool temperature to higher resolution?

Tags: marlin, octoprint

The default displayed and logged resolution of the tool temperature is to 1 decimal place. However, I noticed during autotuning the temperature is recorded to 2 decimal places.

Is it possible to display/log the temperature to 2 decimal places at all times? And if so, how?

I'm using an Ender 3 with Marlin firmware controlled through Octoprint.

Comment: Actually the current temperature isn't accurate enough for 1 decimal, could you explain why you want more "precision".

Comment: To add to 0scar's comment:  neither the bed nor the extruder temperature can be held steady to better than  a couple Kelvins,  so other than  "personal enjoyment," reporting to more digits won't help print quality

Comment: @0scar I am trying to analyse the thermal stability of two different heater blocks for academic purposes and the temperature holds completely steady to 1dp so no fluctuation can be seen. Whereas to 2dp I might be able to see some variation.

Comment: Ah, for comparative studies, using exactly the same thermistor in a controlled temperature environment you could do that, but still, if it is the same for 1 decimal, who would be interested in the second decimal. Remembers me of a report at my company of a colleague who spent a lot of money writing a new report on the noise (dBa) contours including an extra decimal for more accuracy... I would say that it doesn't give you a big reward. But, it is not *my* research! ;-) (In my field, some temperatures are so high and gas flow is so fast, it cannot be measured reliably anyways...)